# How can I do a left join in data.table, Y[X], for two tables with different names, and keep the column names for X?

Tags: r, data.table

When conducting a left join using a Y[X] in data.table for tables with different names, I would like to retain the column names from the table X, here denoted *myx*.

```
myx <- data.table(value = 1:10, key1 = letters[1:10], key2 = toupper(letters[1:10]) ) 
myy <- data.table(value2 = 101:120, diffkey1 = letters[1:20], diffkey2 = toupper(letters[1:20]) ) 

setkey(myx, 'key1', 'key2')
setkey(myy, 'diffkey1', 'diffkey2')

(myx <- myy[myx])

     value2 diffkey1 diffkey2 value
1:    101        a        A     1
2:    102        b        B     2
3:    103        c        C     3
4:    104        d        D     4
5:    105        e        E     5
6:    106        f        F     6
7:    107        g        G     7
8:    108        h        H     8
9:    109        i        I     9
10:    110       j        J    10

# this is the step I would like to avoid
setnames(myx,
     old = c('diffkey1', 'diffkey2'),
     new = c('key1', 'key2'))
```

At the end I have to reset the names and would like to avoid this step.

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider changing the name of the key at the beginning?

```
    myx <- data.table(value = 1:10, key1 = letters[1:10], key2 = toupper(letters[1:10]) ) 
    myy <- data.table(value2 = 101:120, key1 = letters[1:20], key2 = toupper(letters[1:20]) ) 

    setkey(myx, 'key1', 'key2')
    setkey(myy, 'key1', 'key2')

    (myx <- myy[myx])
```

Or you can reverse everything

```
    library(data.table)
    myx <- data.table(value = 1:10, diffkey1 = letters[1:10], diffkey2 = toupper(letters[1:10]) ) 
    myy <- data.table(value2 = 101:120, key1 = letters[1:20], key2 = toupper(letters[1:20]) ) 

    setkey(myx, 'diffkey1', 'diffkey2')
    setkey(myy, 'key1', 'key2')

    (myx <- myy[myx])
```

Comment: The question seems a bit more general than relabelling the columns at the start (i.e. sometimes you can't control that), and still has the 'renaming' step the OP wanted to avoid. Just at the start rather than the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can lookup columns also with the `:=` on join.
You can of course customize LHS for expected column names.

```
library(data.table)
lkp_cols <- names(Y)
X[Y, c(lkp_cols) := mget(paste0("i.",lkp_cols))]
```

This will not work when you expect row explosion on join.

Answer (score 0):

How about `myx[myy,nomatch=0L]`? Don't think it'll be that simple in general, but it works on your example.